# Undefined reference errors from an unneeded library

Tags: c++, ld, undefined-reference

I'm getting some "undefined reference" errors in ld and am at a loss as to what's causing them.

My makefile builds several executables using commands like this:

```
g++ -ogui_program1 -Lpath/to/MyLibs gui_program1.o -lMyUI -lMyBusinessLogic \
    -lMyUtil -lboost_regex
g++ -ogui_program2 -Lpath/to/MyLibs gui_program2.o -lMyUI -lMyBusinessLogic \
    -lMyUtil -lboost_regex
g++ -ocli_program1 -Lpath/to/MyLibs cli_program1.o -lMyUI -lMyBusinessLogic \
    -lMyUtil -lboost_regex
g++ -ocli_program2 -Lpath/to/MyLibs cli_program2.o -lMyUI -lMyBusinessLogic \
    -lMyUtil -lboost_regex
```

And so on.  (Actually, there are quite a few more libraries than this, but this is the general idea.)

`MyUI`, `MyBusinessLogic`, and `MyUtil` are all dynamic libraries that I've already built.  To make writing the makefile simpler, the same list of libraries is used for both GUI and command line programs, even though the command line programs don't need `libMyUI.so`.

One and only one of the command line programs is giving numerous errors about undefined references to Boost.Regex symbols when I try to link it, even though I'm linking `-lboost_regex` with every binary:

```
libMyBusinessLogic.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher >, boost::regex_traits > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
libMyBusinessLogic.so: undefined reference to `boost::cpp_regex_traits::toi(char const*&, char const*, int) const'
libMyBusinessLogic.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match()'
libMyBusinessLogic.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > >, boost::regex_traits > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
libMyBusinessLogic.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > >, boost::regex_traits > >::find()'
libMyBusinessLogic.so: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
libMyBusinessLogic.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher >, boost::regex_traits > >::match()'
```

Linking all other programs works fine.  If I remove `-lMyUI` from the one command-line program, then it works fine, even though `MyUI` doesn't show up anywhere in the error list.

Why isn't ld finding Boost.Regex symbols, when I've added `-lboost_regex` to the end of the command?  Why does removing a seemingly unrelated library fix it?  Why do other programs link without any problems?

Comment: is your libboost_regex.so in path/toMyLibs directory as well? Maybe you need to specify the path in g++ command.

Comment: Addtionally, why does adding `MyUI` to the linking provoke an undefined reference in `MyBusinessLogic`?

Comment: @billz - No, it's using the systemwide libboost_regex.so.  (I even ran it under `strace` to verify.)

Comment: @JoshKelley so an odd, but potentially related question; Does MyBusinessLogic use functionality in MyUI, but the reverse is not true (i.e. MyUI uses nothing from MyBusinessLogic) ? If so, I suggest you flip those two libraries in your link list (told you it was odd, but just do it and report back). Libs should be linked from most-to-least-dependant. Some linkers are just finicky that way. (and gnu's is *notorious* for this).

Comment: @WhozCraig - MyBusinessLogic has no dependencies on MyUI.  (I've tried to link from most-to-least dependent.)  Just to double-check, I swapped the order, and it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out at least most of the answer.  Due to some sloppiness in my makefile rules, `libMyUI.so` was linked against `boost_regex`, but `libMyBusinessLogic.so` wasn't.  I'm guessing that, as a result, linking `MyUI` caused `boost_regex` to get pulled in prematurely, before the linker knew all of the symbols that `MyBusinessLogic` would need from it.

As long as I'm consistent - either all of `My*.so` link with `boost_regex`, or none of them do - everything works.  I'm not sure which of these solutions is most preferred, but at least I have a fix.

Comment: +1 for finding that. Probably wasn't easy, and I can imagine the steps you had to take to finally discover the missing link dependency in your makefile.